# On the Apéry's constant and Euler-Mascheroni constant, Meijer G-Function and a hypergeometric

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification, improper-integrals, special-functions, proof-explanation

Using the closed-form that provide us [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/) of the similar [definite integral involving the Euler-Mascheroni constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant) $$\int_0^\infty e^{-x}\log^3x dx $$

> integrate e^(-x)log^3(x)dx, from x=0 to infinite

one can calculate when do the change of variable $x=e^u$ that $$\int_0^\infty \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{k!}e^{(k+1)u}u^3 du-6-6\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{k!(k+1)^4}=-2\zeta(3)-\gamma^3-\frac{\gamma\pi^2}{2}.$$

After calculate by integration by parts the integral in LHS, and one more time using Wolfram Alpha one can write that

$$3\int_0^\infty x^2 e^{-e^x}dx=3\cdot 2\cdot G_{3,4}^{4,0}\left(1\left|\begin{smallmatrix}1,1,1\\
0,0,0,0\end{smallmatrix}\right.\right),$$ where this RHS is a particular value of the [Meijer G-Function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MeijerG-Function.html), you can see with this code

> integrate x^2 e^(-e^x)dx, from x=0 to infinite.

And finally I've calculated with Wolfram Alfa

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{k! (k+1)^4}=_4F_4(1,1,1,1;2,2,2,2;-1)-1,$$

where in RHS is a particular value of a hypergeometric, see if you need it

> sum (-1)^k/((k+1)^4 k!), from k=1 to infinite.

I would like to clarify if were justified all steps, is not neccesary all calculations, only if were justified, and if there are mistakes, because I've doubts.

> **Question.** Can you provide us a summary as a guideline about how justify the more important steps, those in which could have more doubts? Aren't required the calculations in detail. **Many thanks.**

Comment: I understand that using these special functions I can not get a closed form, but if you know something about previous special functions to get a more interesting identity add a comment or addendum. Thanks for the attention and patience!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want to know something about *Apéry's constant and Euler-Mascheroni constant, Meijer G-Function and a hypergeometric* or simply solve the integral ?

For the first case I cannot help you well (sorry) but for the second case I continue as follows:

Be $ \enspace\displaystyle F(z):=\Gamma(1+z)=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^z}{\prod\limits_{k=1}^n\left(1+\frac{z}{k}\right)}$ . $\hspace{0.5cm}$Value range: It's enough to choose real $z>-1$ .

It’s $\enspace \displaystyle \frac{d}{dz}\ln F(z)|_{z=0}=-\gamma $

and $\enspace\displaystyle \frac{d^k}{dz^k}\ln F(z)|_{z=0}=(-1)^k(k-1)!\zeta(k)\enspace$ for natural number $\enspace k\geq 2$ .

And it’s $\enspace \displaystyle \sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \frac{z^k}{k!} \int\limits_0^\infty e^{-x}(\ln x)^k dx= \int\limits_0^\infty e^{-x} \sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(z\ln x)^k}{k!}dx= \int\limits_0^\infty e^{-x}x^z dx=F(z) $

which leads to $\enspace\displaystyle \int\limits_0^\infty e^{-x}(\ln x)^k dx= \frac{d^k}{dz^k} F(z)|_{z=0}$ . $\hspace{2cm}$ (Taylorseries)

For the case $\enspace k=3\enspace $ we get

$\displaystyle \int\limits_0^\infty e^{-x}(\ln x)^3 dx= F’’’(z)|_{z=0}=$

$\displaystyle =F(z)( (\ln F(z))’^3 +3(\ln F(z))’ (\ln F(z))’’+2(\ln F(z))’’’ )|_{z=0}=-\gamma^3-3\gamma\zeta(2)-2\zeta(3)$ .

Comment: Many thanks for your answer, this afternoon I am going to understand your nice calculations.

Comment: @user243301 : You are welcome. :-)

Comment: Which are welcome are users as you with nice answers in his/her hands, as this. Thanks!!!

Comment: @user243301 In other words [you need $\frac{\Gamma'(s)}{\Gamma(s)} = -\gamma+\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{s+n}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Series_formula) whose $k$th derivative at $s =1$ is something $k! \zeta(k+1)$

Comment: You are welcome @user1952009, many thanks for your claims, now I try think about it. Merci.

Comment: With respect your question @user90369 I understand that the merit is the proof of your integral that show us. And not my calculations that maybe have no a concise mathematical meaning, I am waiting justifications of my calculations, of all those steps that I did: if there are some delicate step in my calculations. Since my question(s) seems more than an open question that a concise question, I am waiting some days and after I consider to accept the answer that better solve my doubts (sometimes are several answer as a companion, the better solution). Thaks one more time.

Comment: @user243301 : Sorry that I cannot help you how to use e.g. Meijer G-Function here (because I have never used it) but I assume that your calculations are right because otherwise it would be unlikely to get the correct result. :-)

Comment: Many thanks one more time, sometimes my questions are confused due my discursive style, and since I did a lot of questions. Then I understand you and say many thanks for your valuable calculations.